# Unable to import from llama_index.vector_stores.opensearch import OpensearchVectorClient

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-language-model, llama-index, ollama

I have installed the below python modules

```
%pip install llama-index-readers-elasticsearch 

%pip install llama-index-vector-stores-opensearch
```

then try to import

```
from llama_index.vector_stores.opensearch import OpensearchVectorClient
```

Getting the following error Can you help to resolve this?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 from llama_index.vector_stores.opensearch import OpensearchVectorClient

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\vector_stores\__init__.py:33
     31 from llama_index.vector_stores.myscale import MyScaleVectorStore
     32 from llama_index.vector_stores.neo4jvector import Neo4jVectorStore
---> 33 from llama_index.vector_stores.opensearch import (
     34     OpensearchVectorClient,
     35     OpensearchVectorStore,
     36 )
     37 from llama_index.vector_stores.pgvecto_rs import PGVectoRsStore
     38 from llama_index.vector_stores.pinecone import PineconeVectorStore

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\vector_stores\opensearch\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from llama_index.vector_stores.opensearch.base import OpensearchVectorStore
      3 __all__ = ["OpensearchVectorStore"]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\vector_stores\opensearch\base.py:7
      4 from typing import Any, Dict, Iterable, List, Optional, Union, cast
      6 from llama_index.core.schema import BaseNode, MetadataMode, TextNode
----> 7 from llama_index.core.vector_stores.types import (
      8     MetadataFilters,
      9     VectorStore,
     10     VectorStoreQuery,
     11     VectorStoreQueryMode,
     12     VectorStoreQueryResult,
     13 )
     14 from llama_index.core.vector_stores.utils import (
     15     metadata_dict_to_node,
     16     node_to_metadata_dict,
     17 )
     18 from opensearchpy import OpenSearch

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\vector_stores\__init__.py:4
      1 """Vector stores."""
----> 4 from llama_index.core.vector_stores.simple import SimpleVectorStore
      5 from llama_index.core.vector_stores.types import (
      6     ExactMatchFilter,
      7     FilterCondition,
   (...)
     12     VectorStoreQueryResult,
     13 )
     15 __all__ = [
     16     "VectorStoreQuery",
     17     "VectorStoreQueryResult",
   (...)
     23     "SimpleVectorStore",
     24 ]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\vector_stores\simple.py:11
      9 import fsspec
     10 from dataclasses_json import DataClassJsonMixin
---> 11 from llama_index.core.indices.query.embedding_utils import (
     12     get_top_k_embeddings,
     13     get_top_k_embeddings_learner,
     14     get_top_k_mmr_embeddings,
     15 )
     16 from llama_index.core.schema import BaseNode
     17 from llama_index.core.utils import concat_dirs

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\indices\__init__.py:4
      1 """LlamaIndex data structures."""
      3 # indices
----> 4 from llama_index.core.indices.composability.graph import ComposableGraph
      5 from llama_index.core.indices.document_summary import (
      6     DocumentSummaryIndex,
      7     GPTDocumentSummaryIndex,
      8 )
      9 from llama_index.core.indices.document_summary.base import DocumentSummaryIndex

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\indices\composability\__init__.py:4
      1 """This module contains all classes used for composing graphs over indices."""
----> 4 from llama_index.core.indices.composability.graph import ComposableGraph
      6 __all__ = ["ComposableGraph"]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\indices\composability\graph.py:5
      1 """Composability graphs."""
      3 from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional, Sequence, Type, cast
----> 5 from llama_index.core.base.base_query_engine import BaseQueryEngine
      6 from llama_index.core.data_structs.data_structs import IndexStruct
      7 from llama_index.core.indices.base import BaseIndex

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\base\base_query_engine.py:17
     15 from llama_index.core.bridge.pydantic import Field
     16 from llama_index.core.callbacks.base import CallbackManager
---> 17 from llama_index.core.prompts.mixin import PromptDictType, PromptMixin
     18 from llama_index.core.schema import NodeWithScore, QueryBundle, QueryType
     20 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\prompts\__init__.py:4
      1 """Prompt class."""
      3 from llama_index.core.base.llms.types import ChatMessage, MessageRole
----> 4 from llama_index.core.prompts.base import (
      5     BasePromptTemplate,
      6     ChatPromptTemplate,
      7     LangchainPromptTemplate,
      8     Prompt,
      9     PromptTemplate,
     10     PromptType,
     11     SelectorPromptTemplate,
     12 )
     13 from llama_index.core.prompts.display_utils import display_prompt_dict
     15 __all__ = [
     16     "Prompt",
     17     "PromptTemplate",
   (...)
     25     "display_prompt_dict",
     26 ]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\prompts\base.py:37
     29 from llama_index.core.base.query_pipeline.query import (
     30     ChainableMixin,
     31     InputKeys,
   (...)
     34     validate_and_convert_stringable,
     35 )
     36 from llama_index.core.bridge.pydantic import BaseModel
---> 37 from llama_index.core.llms.base import BaseLLM
     38 from llama_index.core.llms.generic_utils import (
     39     messages_to_prompt as default_messages_to_prompt,
     40 )
     41 from llama_index.core.llms.generic_utils import (
     42     prompt_to_messages,
     43 )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\llms\base.py:21
     17 from llama_index.core.base.query_pipeline.query import (
     18     ChainableMixin,
     19 )
     20 from llama_index.core.bridge.pydantic import Field, validator
---> 21 from llama_index.core.callbacks import CallbackManager
     22 from llama_index.core.schema import BaseComponent
     25 class BaseLLM(ChainableMixin, BaseComponent):

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\callbacks\__init__.py:4
      2 from .llama_debug import LlamaDebugHandler
      3 from .schema import CBEvent, CBEventType, EventPayload
----> 4 from .token_counting import TokenCountingHandler
      5 from .utils import trace_method
      7 __all__ = [
      8     "CallbackManager",
      9     "CBEvent",
   (...)
     14     "trace_method",
     15 ]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\callbacks\token_counting.py:6
      4 from llama_index.core.callbacks.base_handler import BaseCallbackHandler
      5 from llama_index.core.callbacks.schema import CBEventType, EventPayload
----> 6 from llama_index.core.utilities.token_counting import TokenCounter
      7 from llama_index.core.utils import get_tokenizer
     10 @dataclass
     11 class TokenCountingEvent:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\utilities\token_counting.py:6
      1 # Modified from:
      2 # https://github.com/nyno-ai/openai-token-counter
      4 from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, List, Optional
----> 6 from llama_index.core.llms import ChatMessage, MessageRole
      7 from llama_index.core.utils import get_tokenizer
     10 class TokenCounter:

ImportError: cannot import name 'ChatMessage' from 'llama_index.core.llms' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\llama_index\core\llms\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

In llama-index 0.10.4 I solved the OpensearchVector client import by importing it:

`from llama_index.legacy.vector_stores.opensearch import OpensearchVectorClient`

The other error in your logs `cannot import name 'ChatMessage' from 'llama_index.core.llms'` was happening to me after upgrading a 0.9 version to the latest. It got away after removing llama-index completely and reinstalling 0.10.4 (I saw this in a github issues thread).

Answer (score 0):

to solve

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ChatMessage' from 'llama_index.core.llms'
```

and

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MessageRole' from 'llama_index.core.llms'
```

substitute

```
from llama_index.core.llms import ChatMessage
from llama_index.core.llms import MessageRole
```

with

```
from llama_index.core.chat_engine.types import ChatMessage
from llama_index.core.base.llms.types import MessageRole
```